# How to set initial value for auto_increment in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am quite new for SQL syntax so I am wondering how to set `identity(auto_increment)` value for existing column.

For MySQL it is:

```
ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT = 1001;
```

So basically I need the equivalent of this command for SQL (MS SQL Studio).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you define the identity column you can set the initial value and increment:

```
create table t (
    id int identity(100, 1) primary key,
    . . .
);
```

To set it for an existing column:

```
dbcc checkident ('t', reseed, 100);
```

Comment: To add clarification, the dbcc command you mention is only to reseed an existing identity column, but will not make a non identity column into an identity column. (The question is a little vague, so I am not sure if that is what is needed or not).

Comment: @dmoore1181 . . . This is the equivalent of the MySQL command.

Answer (score 5):

What you need is something along these lines:

```
ALTER TABLE users Add UserId INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1001, 1)
```

Also, if this is an existing column, you may need to create a new column like above without the NOT NULL, insert the values with IDENTITY INSERT set to true, delete the old column, and then you can rename the new column to the old column name and setup any indexes that may have been there as I do not believe that you can change an existing column to be an identity column.

Comment: The column is created as id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1), I just want to set it to value  - for example 1001, so the next could be 1002

Comment: OK, the DBCC command that Gordon has left in his answer should do the trick